# My cats pee/poop outside at certain spots and at certain hours

Tags: behavior, toilet-training

We have two healthy 3 yr old cats, they’re brothers. They do use the litter boxes normally during most of the day but like to do it outside at a few usual spots in the hallway during night to dawn hours. What’s been done:

We usually clear the boxes right after they did their business and wash the boxes at least once a week.

We had them checked by the vet annually. Told the vet about this problem and tested their urine but found nothing wrong.

We cleaned the spots thoroughly after each incident with diluted breach water.

We tried putting the boxes at the spots but they just do it next to the boxes.

It helps if someone stays up and watch them.

Tried putting something like Feliway in the hallway.

Tried taking them to the box right after the incident.

We praised them every time they used the box.

I think we did everything we can but with no avail.

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**Take the cats to the vet *immediately*.**

Failing to use the litterbox can be a symptom of a medical problem, such as a UTI (Urinary Tract Infections). Male cats are especially prone to UTIs, and it can be fatal. Even if it isn't a medical emergency, as I get the impression that this problem has been going on for a while, you should still have your cats seen by a vet. If this problem is quite new and sudden, then it is even more imperative you see a vet ASAP.

**Clean their boxes more frequently.**

Once a week is way too infrequently. I'd do every other day at *minimum.* Once a day or even more frequently is ideal.

**Look for signs of anxiety or stress.**

Cats may also improperly use the box if they are anxious or stressed. Think if there's been any changes around the house, as cats can get very stressed over change. There also could be animals outside the cats are sensing. It could even be an unusual amount of activity in the home. My cat peed outside the box when we deep cleaned the house and bustled around too much as a result. If you can identify a source of stress, do your best to eliminate it.

**Change your litterbox setup.**

Sometimes cats fail to use the litterbox because something about it is no good. Maybe the litter is hurting their paws (when the grain is too coarse), or the box is too small, or the cat is having mobility problems and can't get into it easily.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I wasn’t clear about cleaning the boxes, we clear the boxes almost right after they are used, the once a week cleaning I meant actually wash the boxes. They do use the boxes during the day, which are in the main floor washroom and laundry and one upstairs, we’re tried putting the boxes on the main floor in the hallway but they just do it next to the boxes. Don’t notice any stress, they are very playful and well loved. We had them examined by the vet and tested their urine and found nothing wrong, she suggested using Feliway but that didn’t work.

Comment: In that case, I think the most likely explanations are anxiety/stress (perhaps there is something happening at night only that stresses them, like wild animals. A motion detecting sprinkler can help with that) or they don't like the box. As for cleaning, you might want to get a black light and examine around your home, because cat pee might no longer be apparent, but will still show up with blacklight. That way you can be extra sure you cleaned it all.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it sounds like they are marking their territory.

That's natural behavior for adult cats. They spray urine at walls, furniture or other objects to deliberately leave their smell on these objects. That warns other cats not to enter their territory and attracts female cats when they are in heat.

Desexing male cats early in life usually stops this instinct completely. Since yours are 3 years already, there's a chance, but no guarantee that will ever stop marking. At least the urine won't smell as badly after desexing.

---

And cleaning a litter box only once a week is by far not enough. You have to remove the feces daily (because some parasites can only be transmitted by day-old feces) and should also remove the urine daily (works best with clumping litter). Imagine you had to use a toilet that only flushes once a week...

Comment: Thanks. They were neutered about 6 months old. When I said cleaning the boxes once a week I meant washing the boxes, we clear the boxes almost every time after they used it. Rarely more than one use before clearing

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're doing a lot! I was in a similar boat very recently with one of my cats and was surprised that changing the litter we used fixed the issue entirely and instantly! We switched to "Dr. Elsey's" litter and both cats seem to really like it.

Comment: Thanks! Will give that a try, fingers crossed.